# How to get different file append

Tags: bash, shell

so I've got a loop setup that goes through a set of tests

```
for file in ./tests/firstseries/*.test; do
# Now as I go through single one of them I compare my result with expected result
  returned=$(./myexecute "$file")
  expected=$(cat tests/firstseries/"$file".output
if [ "$returned" -eq "$expected" ]; then
   ...
```

You get the drill. Issue is, since my for loop asserts file as `(PATH)/file.test` if I do what I did with my cat to get the expected output, it ends up searching for `"(PATH)/file.test.output"`. Any idea how to make it look only for `"(PATH)/file.output"` ?

So to put it frank I want to go through all files in a directory with ending of .test, then execute the .test file and compare it with a value from a file in the same directory with ending of .output

For example my directory "firstseries would be"

> **firstseries**
>   test1.test
>   test1.output
>   test2.test
>   test2.output

1) For loop for all the files ending with .test
2) Execute the desired .test file (in this case test1.test)
3) Get the value from file test1.output (not test1.test.output)
4) Compare the two values
4) repeat

Comment: `PATH` or `PWD`? What exactly do you mean by `PATH`?

Comment: Do you want the expected to be the same name as `$file` but with a different ending (output instead of test)?

Comment: @arco444 Didn't mean $PATH that is commonly reffered to as in shell, but rather the actual path to the file i defined beforehand.

Comment: Use a combination of dirname : https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname and basename : https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename - that should sort your problems :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this line:

```
expected=$(< "${file%.*}.output")
```

Comment: Use `$(< "${file%.*}.output)` to avoid spawning an extra process to read the file.

Comment: @chepner cool, you opened up a new world for me. I'm also forced to work on tcsh during much of my time so this is also a source of aggravation now :) ...